# Can old camcorder be optimized?

Tags: camcorder

I bought a camera in 2003. Since then, I think something might have  become dusty, or some parts could have become worn out (or etc, I dont know)..

What steps I can take to refresh the old camera (in order to get it's maximum quality again, like new)?

(p.s. My camera is a JVC 3CCD, records on SD card).

[image: Image depicting a JVC 3CCD]

Comment: What are the symptoms that make you think something is worn out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Probably not.

1. I believe your camera records video on MiniDV. Video is written digitally but writing process is the only non-digital operation in the camera (involves magnetic head, tape, and tape scrolling mechanism). It's easy to determine if something is really become worn out because usually something mechanical is the only thing that can gradually degrade. If you observe too many digital artifacts in your fresh recordings (make sure it's not because of old MiniDVs) you can try to clean the head (google 'tape head cleaning'). If it doesn't help then almost certainly something is wrong with the head/scrolling.
2. Water or steam can get into your camera, condense there, and make the image slightly blurred (I had such an issue with my Sony camera that is similar to yours). If you are not 100 % sure that the image was less blurred earlier skip this point.

In both cases I don't recommend you to try opening/repairing the camera by yourself. Go to the official service. This brings us to the price of repair which is probably comparable to the camera's cost for such an old device. That's why I recommend you to invest the money in a new camera (progressive video, no need to buy tapes, less requirements for light and so on) or stick with existing issues. So the answer is probably not.

Comment: it records on SD card.. thanks anyway!

Comment: Wow, camera from 2003 writes on cards. I should have checked the specs before writing, pardon. Then moreover nothing can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague to be answered properly. Exactly what parts of "quality" have degraded?  How do you know the camera isn't operating as good as when it was new?  Is the video not focused sharply?  Are the colors "off"?  Is the audio distorted?  You can only repair or improve SPECIFIC problems. Otherwise it is just free-floating anxiety for which there is no technical solution.  If you can list specific issues, then you may get specific suggestions.